# Making an array producing parents and children of records

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I cannot figure out how to make a parent, child (by an id) that be put into an new array from an array (loaded by a database).

I need it to be like this:

```
+- Parent - ID: 4
|
+---- Child record  
+---- Child record  <-- these children have a parent_id of 4
+---- Child record
|
+- Parent - ID: 5
|
+---- Child record 
+---- Child record
+---- Child record
+---- Child record  <-- these children have a parent_id of 5
+---- Child record 
|
+- Parent - ID: 7
|
+---- Child record  
+---- Child record  <-- these children have a parent_id of 7
+---- Child record
```

And so on, the record loaded from the database looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [info] => this is a child, since sub is 1 and parent_id contains a number
            [sub] => 1
            [parent_id] => 4
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [info] => this is a parent, since sub is 0 and parent_id does not contain a number
            [sub] => 0
            [parent_id] => 
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [info] => this is a child, since sub is 1 and parent_id contains a number
            [sub] => 1
            [parent_id] => 4
        )

.... more records
```

The SQL is ordered in ascending mode by the row `id`, the new array containing parents and child of records what it's basically for.

Comment: Sorry if I don't make sense, I'm tired and please if you need any clarifications, I'll add more.

Comment: Sorry it doesn't make sense. You're trying to create the array from a database query? Or there's another data structure you have in PHP you want to convert?

Comment: Actually when I looked at your question more thouroughly I noticed the weird instance when an info is a parent how would you like to approach that would you like the info to be associated with the children?

Comment: So did it accomplish what you were looking for??? Just want to know if I hit on the nose or did you need to do some tweaking?

Comment: Pretty good. :-) I'll come back if I run across a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach($dbArray as $row)
{
    if($row['parent_id'] != "")
    {
        $parentArray[$row['parent_id']][]['child'] = $row['info'];

    }
    else
    {
        $parentArray[$row['id']]['parent'] = $row['info'];
    }

}
```

this is where the parent id is the key for the array of child info
The resulting array would look something like this

```
Array(
/*parent id*/
    [0]=>Array(
       [parent] => //whatever info
       [0] => Array(
               [child]=> //whatever child info
                   )

           )
      )
```

Comment: Looks good, but I believe the OP wants the entire child record, not just the info attribute.

Comment: would you want all the parent info and all child info in the array?